# Функция изменяет переменную, объявленную вне функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list

Как сделать так, чтобы переменная вне функции не изменялась?

Есть список:

```
list_1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'cow', 'mouse']
```

Есть функция:

```
def animals(mass):
    new_list = []
    if len(mass) == 1:
        new_list.append(mass[0])
    else:
        while len(mass) > 0:
            new_list.append(mass[0])
            del mass[0]
            
            if len(mass) == 1:
                new_list.append(mass[0])
                break

    return new_list
```

После выполнения `animals(list_1)`, 
список `list_1` режется и становится просто **`['mouse']`**

В проекте эта функция добавляет кнопки на основании списка, но при повторном обращении к этому списку, добавляется всего одна кнопка.

Как можно оставить список без изменений?

Comment: Ну, сохранить значения из списка, потом вызвать эту функцию, и если надо снова ее вызвать, берем сохраненные значения

Comment: Замени всю функцию на `return mass[:]`

Answer (score 3):

Вам надо выполнить глубокое копирование:

```
list_copy = copy.deepcopy(list_1)
```

Или изменить логику, например так:

```
list_1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'cow', 'mouse']

def animals(mass):
    new_list = []

    if len(mass) == 1:                                           # ???
        new_list.append(mass[0])
    else:
#        while len(mass) > 0:
        for i, item in enumerate(mass):                          # +++
            new_list.append(f'{item}_{i}')
#            del mass[0]
            
            if len(mass) == i-1:                                 # +++
                new_list.append(f'{item}_{i}')
#                break

    return new_list      

n_list = animals(list_1)

print(f'\nn_list = {n_list}') #
print(f'list_1 = {list_1}\n') #
```

Выведет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем глубокое копирование, если вложенных объектов нет?

Comment: @Amgarak ну так написал, а почему нет. Да и я свой вариант написал и в нем нет ни копирования, ни удаления.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша функция изменяет исходный список list_1, так как фактически вы ссылаетесь на объекты её ячеек. Можно просто создать копию(срез) списка и работать уже с ним, тогда исходные данные не будут изменены.

```
list_1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'cow', 'mouse']

def animals(mass):
    new_list = []
    mass_copy = mass[:]  # Создаем копию/срез списка
    if len(mass_copy) == 1:
        new_list.append(mass_copy[0])
    else:
        while len(mass_copy) > 0:
            new_list.append(mass_copy[0])
            del mass_copy[0]
            
            if len(mass_copy) == 1:
                new_list.append(mass_copy[0])
                break

    return new_list

result = animals(list_1)
print(result)
print(list_1)  # Список list_1 остается как был
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно отметить, что методы списков, в отличие от строковых методов, изменяют сам список, а потому результат выполнения затирает значения внутри ИМЕЮЩЕГОСЯ списка.
Чтобы этого не происходило , просто копируйте ваш список и работайте в функции с копией.
Например вот так:

```py
list_1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'cow', 'mouse']
list_2 = list_1.copy() 
...
animals(list_2)
```

Comment: Вы правы , исправлю.

Answer (score -1):

можно создать копию списка и работать с ней с помощью copy
https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html вот документация